# Perfect squares relantionship

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

Find all natural numbers $\overline{xyzt}=10^3x+10^2y+10z+t$ who satisfies the following condition
$$ \sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{y}+3\sqrt{\overline{zy}}+4\sqrt{z}=t^2. $$

Comment: Are different variables mean  different numbers?

Comment: I guess there are a lots of pairs who can match that condition. I want to limit down the possibilities and find them all.

Comment: So why I got so many negative reviews? Put on hold and other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is true, though I don't know whether there is any simple proof of this, that no linear combination of irrational square roots can be rational. In that case, each of the square roots in your condition must be integral. In particular, $\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{\overline{zy}}$ and $\sqrt{z}$ must all be integers. But this limits $\,y,z \in \{0,1,4,9\},\,$ so either $\,z=0\,$ or $\,\overline{zy}=49\,$.

If $\,z=0\,$, the condition simplifies to $\,\sqrt{x}+5\sqrt{y}=t^2.\,$ Since $\,0 \le \sqrt{n} \le 3\,$ for single-digit $n$'s, we have that $\,0 \le t^2 \le 18,\,$ and excluding the trivial $\,x=y=z=t=0\,$ case, that leaves $\,t^2 \in \{1,4,9,16\}.\,$ A little trial and error gives the only solutions to be $\,\overline{xyzt}=1001\,$ and $\,1904.\,$

If $\,\overline{zy}=49,\,$ the condition simplifies to $\,\sqrt{x}+35=t^2,\,$ and the bounds on $\,\sqrt{x}\,$ force $\,t^2=36,\,$ i.e. $\,x=1,\,$ which yields the single solution $\,\overline{xyzt}=1946.\,$

Thus the only solutions are

$$\overline{xyzt}=\boxed{1001,1904,1946}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! all the best!

Answer (score 1):

$$x=y=z=9$$ and $$\overline{zy}=81$$ gives $48$ so $$t<7$$
Further $$x=y=z=1$$ and $$\sqrt{\overline{zy}}=\sqrt{16}=4$$ gives $$t\geq 5$$ so we have $$5\le t\le 6$$, we have only two cases to consider $$t=5,t=6$$